# Configuring MiniProfiler to work on multiple domains

Tags: mvc-mini-profiler

I want to add MiniProfiler to a project with multiple domains servicing requests:

1. application.domain.com (Serves all HTML, JavaScript etc)
2. api.domain.com (REST/JSON API)

One of the best features of MiniProfiler is how AJAX calls show up, out of the box the above doesn't work. Does anyone have any suggestions on an approach / configuration I could use to enable MiniProfiler events from api.domain.com to show up on pages in application.domain.com?

Comment: I'm curious about this as well. I have MiniProfiler setup in a ASP.NET MVC 4 site and the profiler renders the results as expected but fails to display the results from AJAX requests to the API on another domain. I’m concerned the X-MiniProfiler-Ids response header is getting lost after the preflighted request. I’ve tried adding a Access-Control-Expose-Headers header but it's still missing on my API response.

Comment: I have the same problem on a single domain, where the API is a separate project from the Web. A .NET MVC4 web app with a separate Web API project in the same solution and both running from localhost, same port.  Issue is the calls from the Web to the API return nothing but the JSON data and its not picked up by the profiler.  Installed Miniprofiler to the Web API project too and still nothing.  The Web API project help pages display the Miniprofiler info, but testing the api yields nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done, but would require some extra setup steps on your part:

1. Set up the `MiniProfiler.Settings.Storage` to save to some storage medium (like a redis cache or sql server) that is accessible from all domains. That will allow all domains being profiled to save their results together.
2. Be sure to set `MiniProfiler.Current.User` to have the same value on all domains. The default behavior when retrieving results is to show all results for a specific user. So you want to make sure that profiles for the same user are being stored consistently across multiple domains.